# Can a 3-phase rectifier handle input from a 1-phase/2-phase source?

Tags: rectifier, three-phase

In trying to homebrew a miniature wind-turbine using the stepper out of the tray motor from the CD Drive (sloth that I am) I'm loath to go to the effort of constructing a rectifier, and a regulator. This miniature may grow up to become one from dish-washing machine motor ... but that is an AC motor. Anyway, that is for a later date...

An [RR](http://www.wemoto.com/info/Regulator_Rectifier/) for the [scooter](http://auto.indiamart.com/mopeds-scooterettes/tvs-scooty/technical-specification-tvs-scooty-pep+.html) was purchased, and never put in. The output from the turbine may be dumped to the RR for rectification. However an RR is meant for 3-phase input.

IMO, please correct me if I'm wrong, if it can handle 3-phase it shall probably handle 1-phase as well ... Hence the question - can a multi-phase RR do it's magic if fed single-phase input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A three phase bridge rectifier can easily be configured as a single phase type. What you need to watch out for is: -

1. Voltage rating is sufficient
2. Current rating is sufficient
3. It's fast enough to efficiently handle whatever frequency you are
   putting its way
4. It can deal with surges into charging the smoothing capacitor involved

As you haven't mentioned any of these you'll have to check your self.